# How to get how many pixels I moved on a MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE event in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a touch listener that watches for ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, and ACTION_UP.

I want to get the number of pixels moved, but I can't find anything in the documentation that allows this.

```
} else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                float x2 = motionEvent.getX();
                float y2 = motionEvent.getY();
                            //Logging x2 and y2....
```

My log outputs pretty big numbers, even though I move very very slightly.

I try to move 1 pixel in either direction with my mouse pointer, but I get results like 42 for x and 75 for y. I'm guessing getX() and getY() do not respond with what I think they respond with.

EDIT:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {


        float startX = 0;
        float startY = 0;


        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            startX = motionEvent.getRawX();
            startY = motionEvent.getRawY();
            Log.e("resize", "action down");

        } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            Log.e("resize", "action move");


            float movedX = motionEvent.getRawX() - startX;
            float movedY = motionEvent.getRawY() - startY;

            Log.e("", " movement "+movedX+" "+movedY+"");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getX()` and `getY()` are coordinates of point *on the view* in which motion event was fired, calculated *relatively to view's initial size and position*. It means that if your view was rotated or scaled, these coordinates are recalculated using rotation and scale matrix.

To get absolute screen coordinates, you should use `getRawX()` and `getRawY()` instead.

To obtain vector at which finger moved from the starting point, first you need to remember point at which ACTION_DOWN event was fired:

```
if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
   startX = event.getRawX();
   startY = event.getRawY();
}
```

Then, when finger moves, calculate movement coordinates relative to this starting point:

```
if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
    movedX = event.getRawX() - startX;
    movedY = event.getRawY() - startY;
}
```

Comment: Actually. This doesn't seem to work. When I log movedX or movedY I seemingly get only the rawX value. I think that since I have to initialize startX and startY that they are getting set to 0 every time I move.

Comment: @user2676468 this is because you're resetting startX and startY to 0 every time motion event fires. You should move their declaration out of `onTouch()` method